# Using data from a table in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel

By example:

table1

```
Position     Salary
Seller       150
Management   200
Technical    120
Maintenance  100
```

table2 (in same sheet or in a different sheet that doesn't matter)

```
Name     Position          salary
John     Seller             ?
Paul     Technical          ?
Julia    Management         ?
Martha   Seller             ?
George   Technical          ?
Ringo    Maintenance        ?
```

How can I put the salary corresponding in third column?

I've already selected `Data->Validation->List` for Position in `table2`, 
But how can I fill the "`salary`" column automatically?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `VLOOKUP`

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2, FALSE)` Given your stated tables, assuming the first one is Sheet2 and your second is Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is about Excel-table;

In Excel when you select a list and apply `Format as Table` on it; that range automatically takes a name, that you can find it in `[TABLE TOOLS] DESIGN` additional tab, in the box of `Table Name`, like `Table1` and you can change it to your favorite name.

You can use the name of that table for reaching columns and etc, like:

```
Table1  --> All columns and all rows in the table criteria.
Table1[Col1]  --> Range of column of 'col1' from the below row of the header to last row of table.
Table[[Col1]:[Col3]] --> Range of columns between 'col1' to 'col2'.

=[@[Col1]] --> This formula returns the value of `Col1` from current row of that column.
```

> **Recommendation:**
>   When you use this range specifying changes to table don't harm your related formulas.

---

So, you can use that ranges in your formulas like:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Position];Table1[[Position]:[Salary]];2;FALSE)
```

or (*recommended*):

```
=INDEX(Table1[Salary]; MATCH([@Position];Table1[Position];0))
```